# Google API PHP Client cannot get contacts

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I used the code like line 49 to line 54 of this https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/contacts/simple.php
But, I got the invalid_grant error. I went to Google APIs Console, I cannot file Google Contacts service to grant.

Please help me.

Comment: Hi,
Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the proper settings on the following lines?  You will need to create the appliation settings at the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console#access) and then plug those settings into your code below.  This code worked perfect for me once all the settings were correct.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Contacts PHP Sample');
$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
// Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=contacts to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
// $client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
// $client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
// $client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_redirect_uri');
// $client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_developer_key');
```

Comment: it is not working!
Seems that google updated API and now it could not be correct
do you know what should change to use it now!?